# I couldn't get 2 NICs working together on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, routing, nic

I've got an Ubuntu 10.04 server with this configuration:

eth0: 192.168.10.XXX mask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.10.254
eth1: 192.168.0.XXX mask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.0.3

eth0 is used for incoming and outgoing trafic (internal webserver)
eth1 i want to use for accessing the network: 192.168.51.0/24 by gateway 192.168.0.1

when eth1 is down, the webserver is reachable.

When i want to bring the state of eth1 to up, i use the following commands:

```
$ sudo su
# ifconfig eth1 up
# route add -net 192.168.51.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.0.1
# ping 192.168.51.XXX
[i've got contact]

# ip route add default via 192.168.10.254
# ping 192.168.51.XXX
[i've got contact]
```

but when i want to access the webserver, i can't get contact.

Can someone please give me some advice so the network .51 AND the webserver (network .10) is reachable?

Comment: How are the reply packets the webserver sends supposed to get back to this server? It sounds like you've done half the job -- making this machine send the outbound `ping` packets to `192.168.0.1`, but what about the second half -- making the web server send the `ping` reply packets back along the correct path?

Comment: ping result from local:
ping 192.168.10.2: 100% packet loss
ping 192.168.0.237: 0% packet loss

ping result from server:
ping 192.168.10.254: 0% packet loss
ping 192.168.0.3: 0% packet loss
ping 192.168.0.1: 0%packet loss
ping 192.168.51.100: 0% packet loss

Comment: Please provide the output of `ip route` and `ip addr` when both interfaces are up. What IP are you trying to access the webserver from?

Answer (score 0):

### I've got the solution!

The command i had executed was:

```
# route del -net 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 eth1
```

After that command my: 0 network, 10 network AND 51 network was accessible.
I also edit `/etc/sysctl.conf` and uncomment `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` before, but i'm not sure if this is necessary.

my configs:

## ifconfig -a

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:29:e0:03:9c  
          inet addr:192.168.10.2  Bcast:192.168.10.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fee0:39c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:53794 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:53916 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:6812117 (6.8 MB)  TX bytes:21573511 (21.5 MB)

eth0:1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:29:e0:03:9c  
          inet addr:192.168.10.10  Bcast:192.168.10.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:29:e0:03:a6  
          inet addr:192.168.0.237  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fee0:3a6/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:29845 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:469 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2555869 (2.5 MB)  TX bytes:42872 (42.8 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:8157 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8157 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:624350 (624.3 KB)  TX bytes:624350 (624.3 KB)
```

## route -n

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.51.0    192.168.0.1     255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 eth1
192.168.10.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         192.168.10.254  0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         192.168.10.254  0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         192.168.10.254  0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
```

## /etc/network/interfaces

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static 
address 192.168.10.2
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.10.254

auto eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
address 192.168.10.10
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.10.254

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 192.168.0.237
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.0.1
post-up route add -net 192.168.51.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.0.1
```